# Group form elements in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have `jQuery` `Mobile/PHP/MySQL` site with a long list of similar forms (with different input values but not different element ids). Two examples below. I could have the buttons submit the forms but since it's a very long list that I don't want to reload every time a button is clicked I would prefer to use `JS/AJAX` calls to add/delete values in the database. If I use JS for this, is there a way to get the input values from a specific form sent to the function called by the button in this form?

```html
<form>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input name="field1" placeholder="" value="value1" type="text">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input name="field2" placeholder="" value="value2"
                type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a data-role="button">
                Add
            </a>
            <a data-role="button">
                Delete
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input name="field1" placeholder="" value="value1" type="text">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input name="field2" placeholder="" value="value2"
                type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a data-role="button">
                Add
            </a>
            <a data-role="button">
                Delete
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: First things first: You have multiple elements with the same ID within the same document? It's probably a good idea to reconsider that and make those IDs unique.

Comment: Thanks, removed the ids. I don't think they are required.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden input to save current operation:

```
<input type='hidden' id='op' name='op' class='op' value=''/>
```

Save click event to input when button clicked using JS:

```
$('#addButton').unbind('click'); // prevent jqm binding twice
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    $('.op').val('add');
});
$('#deleteButton').unbind('click'); 
$('#deleteButton').click(function(){
    $('.op').val('del');
});>
```

Get `$_POST['op']` on server side and dispatch your event:

```
switch($_REQUEST['op']){
    case 'add':{
    // do something
    }
    break;

    case 'del':{
    // do something
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### IDs

IDs **MUST** be unique document-wide!
HTML4 DTD (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html):

```
<!ENTITY % coreattrs  
 "id          ID             #IMPLIED  -- document-wide unique id --  
  class       CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- space-separated list of classes --  
  style       %StyleSheet;   #IMPLIED  -- associated style info --
  title       %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- advisory title --"
  >;
```

You are looking for jQuery.serializeArray (http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

### Example

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(
    var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            form: formData
        }
    });
));
```

Server side:

```
<?php
$formData = array();
if (!empty($_POST['form']) && is_array($_POST['form'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['form'] as $element) {
        if (empty($element['name']) || empty($element['value'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $formData[$element['name']] = $element['value'];
    }
    unset($_POST['form']);
}
var_dump($formData); // <-- See structured output
```

*(untested)*

### Docs

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html
- http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/
- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

this may help

JS

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
    form.find('input').each(
            ...//do rest of logic
});
```

Note:

Using same id for many html element is not recommended